# All possible variations of terms to add up to sum in a given amount of piles?

Tags: javascript, combinations

How to get all possible variations of terms to add up to sum, in a given amount of piles, using javascript?
Let's say I have a sum of 10 and I want to split this into 4 piles with positive terms and zeros only.

```
function getCombinations(sum, piles){
    ...
}
getCombinations(10,4);
```

Returns something like this in a two dimensional array:

```
[
    [3,3,3,1],
    [3,3,1,3],
    [7,1,1,1],
    [10,0,0,0],
    ...
]
```

It's not mandatory to return [3,3,3,1] and [3,3,1,3] as different solutions, fastest way will do. I will only work with small numbers, max sum will probably be 10.

It's a variation of the Count the coins problem, http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_the_coins, but I want the solutions returned, I have a given set of piles and I use all positive terms (and zero) not only specific coin values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```js
const matrix = (num, cols) => {
  const matrix = [[num, ...[...Array(cols-1)].map(() => 0)]];
  const hashes = new Set;
  const coef = Math.pow(10, cols-1);
  let digits = 10 * coef - 1;

  while (digits-- >= coef) {
    const nums = ('' + digits).split('').map(d => +d);
    const hash = nums.sort((a, b) => b - a).join('');
    if (hashes.has(hash) || nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) !== num)
      continue;
    hashes.add(hash);
    matrix.push(nums);
  }
  return matrix;
};

console.log(matrix(10, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pratical way of doing this:

```
function getCombinations(sum, piles){
   var array =[];
      for(var i = 1; i <= piles; i ++) {

   var subArray = Array.apply(null, Array(4)).map(
        function () {  
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * sum)});
 
   array.push(subArray);
 

  }
   return array;
}
 var result = getCombinations(10,4);
```

Comment: I get an array with undefined with this.

Comment: I´ve edited it, so you can try once again. The RETURN keyword must be in the same line as the ITEM being returned. Then is gonna work.

Comment: This doesn't return what I expected. The numbers in the piles should add up to sum, like in my example return array. And I need all possible combinations for this.